# Make a Name Sequence

Tags: sql, oracle, sequence

I have table like this

```
file_nbr    name_seq    Person_name

10  1   James Linson

10  1   Ronn Dave

10  1   Michael Meyer

12  1   Pamela  J. Mayberry  

12  1   Randall M. Bachtel 

12  1   Cleary E. Mahaffey 

12  1   D. Scott Rowley

12  1   Stephen  L. Phelps 

12  1   Mark A. Bennet

12  1   Richard  P. Lewis
```

I want to change the name_seq, so the result like this:

```
10  1   James Linson

10  2   Ronn Dave

10  3   Michael Meyer

12  1   Pamela  J. Mayberry  

12  2   Randall M. Bachtel 

12  3   Cleary E. Mahaffey 

12  4   D. Scott Rowley

12  5   Stephen  L. Phelps 

12  6   Mark A. Bennet

12  7   Richard  P. Lewis
```

What's the best SQL query?

Comment: you should remove tabs with spaces to get the columns properly aligned, and probably remove the blank lines as well.

Answer (score 4):

```
WITH records
AS
(
    SELECT  "file_nbr",
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY "file_nbr" ORDER BY "file_nbr") "name_seq",
            "Person_name"
    FROM    TableName
)
SELECT  "file_nbr", "name_seq", "Person_name"
FROM    records
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d7dd1/1)

Comment: +1 I really need to take some time to learn how this over/partition syntax works!

Comment: @Sepster - it's all in the docs http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174

Comment: It's redundant to `ORDER BY file_nbr` if you're already `PARTITION`ing by it - the `ORDER BY` is *within* a partition, so it's effectively sorted in whatever order the rows get examined.

Comment: You [need an order by clause](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions156.htm) though; `order by null` would be sufficient and might be clearer, to indicate there is no real ordering within the partition.